# MotionLayout throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when adding three or more CustomAttribute elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am unable to add 3rd `customColorValue`, `customIntegerValue` or `customFloatValue` in a `MotionLayout`'s `MotionScene`. `MotionController` keeps throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here is a simple layout that can easily reproduce this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene">


    <com.spruce.messenger.composer.MessageTypeButton
        android:id="@+id/messageType"
        style="@style/messageTypeSelectionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

`motion_scene` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="100"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
            motion:maxAcceleration="18"
            motion:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/messageType"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="left"
            motion:touchRegionId="@+id/messageType" />
    </Transition>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/messageType">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="StrokeTintColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#D68739" />
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="TextColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#2D70FF" />
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundTint"
                motion:customColorValue="#F1F6FF" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/messageType">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="StrokeTintColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#D68739" />
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="TextColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#D68739" />
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundTint"
                motion:customColorValue="#FFFCF3" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

I keep getting following exception as soon as I add 3rd `customColorValue`, `customIntegerValue` or `customFloatValue`:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionController.setup(MotionController.java:592)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.setupMotionViews(MotionLayout.java:1196)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.access$700(MotionLayout.java:820)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout$Model.reEvaluateState(MotionLayout.java:1850)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.onMeasure(MotionLayout.java:1977)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Also filed a bug just in case https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151823

Comment: This issue is now fixed. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151823#comment7